# Checking JSP Input for "Empty"

Tags: java, jsp

In my testing, the following seems to cover everything I can think of in terms of ensuring that a field is populated.  Can anyone think of a case I might have missed?

```
public static boolean isEmpty(final String string) {
    return string != null && !string.isEmpty() && !string.trim().isEmpty();
}
```

Comment: The 2nd check is superfluous as the 3rd check already does that.

Comment: return string != null && !string.trim().isEmpty(); Change your method's name to isNotEmpty, because it is what it really checks.

Comment: "!string.isEmpty()" is redundant in this case.

Comment: Seems OK to me, except the method should be named `isNotBlank()` as in... Apache commons-lang `StringUtils.isNotBlank()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name is a bit misleading as the method is labeled "isEmpty" but will return true when it's not empty... but that's up to you.

I would change your AND statements to ORs and remove the middle term as it is superfluous e.g.

```
public static boolean isEmpty(final String string) {
  return string == null || string.trim().isEmpty();
}
```

**EXAMPLE:**

```
    if(isEmpty(null)){
        System.out.println("Empty");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Not Empty");
    }
    if(isEmpty("")){
        System.out.println("Empty");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Not Empty");
    }
    if(isEmpty(" ")){
        System.out.println("Empty");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Not Empty");
    }
    if(isEmpty("Test")){
        System.out.println("Empty");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Not Empty");
    }
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
 Empty
 Empty
 Empty
 Not Empty
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a library?

One example is Apache's Common Utils:

[StringUtils.isBlank()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isBlank%28java.lang.String%29)

[StringUtils.isNotBlank()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isNotBlank%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Commons StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) uses the following techniques:

[isEmpty](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.lang.String%29):

```
public static boolean isEmpty(String str) {
    return str == null || str.length() == 0;
}
```

[isBlank](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isBlank%28java.lang.String%29):

```
public static boolean isBlank(String str) {
    int strLen;
    if (str == null || (strLen = str.length()) == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < strLen; i++) {
        if ((Character.isWhitespace(str.charAt(i)) == false)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just do:

```
public static boolean isEmpty(String string) { //don't make it final going in or you cant trim it.
    string = string.trim();
    return string != null || string.length() == 0;
}
```

Comment: "//don't make it final going in or you cant trim it." You can run the trim method on a final String.

Comment: This will throw a `NullPointerException` if `string` is `null`.